# Two circles touches each other externally at the point O. ..

Tags: geometry

I am stuck on the following elementary problem that says:

> Two circles touches each other externally at the point O. If PQ and RS are two diameters of these two circles respectively and $PQ || RS$ (Where || indicates parallel),then prove that P,O,S  are collinear.

[image]

My Try: 
 I added the points P,O,S and also the points Q,O; ans R,O.

From the given condition , $\angle POQ=90^{\circ}=\angle ROS$. [since,Any angle inscribed in a semi-circle is a right angle.]

Now,from the figure we see  $\angle POR=180^{\circ}-90^{\circ}=\angle QOS$.
And hence,$\angle POQ+\angle QOS=90^{\circ}+90^{\circ}=180^{\circ}=\angle POS$.

Hence ,we can conclude P,O,S are collinear.

Can someone verify it ? Am I right?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Is it $PQ//RS$? Also how do you conclude $\angle POR=180^{\circ}-90^{\circ}=\angle QOS$?

Comment: your solution is not right because when you write $\angle POR=180º-90º$ you are assuming that $P,O,S$ are collinear.

Comment: $PR$ and $RS$ can never be parallel!! You have to correct the question.

Comment: I am extremely sorry for the typo..and also for the late reply..It will be PQ || RS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that your approach is valid, since you have assumed that $QOR$ and $POS$ are collinear and then calculated

$\angle POR=180^{\circ}-90^{\circ}=\angle QOS$

What you can do instead, is to draw the line between centers of circles. The center of the left circle is $C_1$ and the right one is $C_2$. Also, draw a line from $P$ to $S$. Note that we do not know if $PS$ passes $O$. The line that passes through the centers meets $PS$ at $X$. Now, you can easily see that triangles $PC_1X$ and $SC_2X$ are similar. Therefore, the ratio of their edges is

$\frac{|C_1P|}{|C_2S|}=\frac{|C_1X|}{|C_2X|}=\frac{r_1}{r_2}$

Where $r_1$ and $r_2$ are radius of the circles.

Therefore, we know that $X$ is on the line $C_1C_2$ and it also has to satisfy the ratio. So, it should be the same as $O$.

To be more specific, we have two equations and two unknowns

$|C_1X|+|C_2X|=r_1+r_2$

$\frac{|C_1X|}{|C_2X|}=\frac{r_1}{r_2}$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the lucid explanation...

Comment: My pleasure, without any pressure.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

One result very known is that: *both centers and the tangent point are collinear*. So $A,O,B$ are collinear.

One way to prove that $P,O,S$ are collinear is conclude that $\angle AOP=\angle BOS$.

Once $\overline{PQ} \parallel \overline{RS}$ then $\angle PAO=\angle OBS$ (Thales Theorem) and also:

$$\frac{AP}{AO}=\frac{OB}{BS}=1$$

then the triangles $PAO$ and $OBS$ are similars by the case SAS. That give us $\angle AOP=\angle BOS$ and then $POS$ are collinear.

Answer (score 1):

Flip the smaller circle (lets suppose its the one with diameter $RS$) about the common tangent at O, so that its now internally tangent. Let $R'$ and $S'$ be the reflected points corresponding to $R$ and $S$ resp.

The homothety centred at O now carries this circle into the larger circle, also carrying $R'$ to $P$ as well as $S'$ to $Q$ which means $OR'P$ is a straight line, and similarly $OS'Q$ is also a straight line.

So $ORS$ being a reflection of $OR'S'$ has $\angle POQ = \angle ROS$ which is what we need to conclude that $POS$ and $QOR$ are straight lines.

Answer (score 0):

$ POQ,ROS$ are right angles because they are contained in a semi-circle, by Thales theorem.

EDIT1:

My bad, an error occured before.

Imagine two disjunct  right triangles hinged at right angle vertex with discontinuous slope. Unless alternate angles at diameters are equal a same line continuity  cannot be established. When cyan right triangle at right is rotated so that $ \beta = B $ these are alternate angles. So the transversal cutting line through $O$ has to be single continuous cutting line.

[image: TgtsCircles]

Comment: Good argument but you didn't use the fact that PQ || RS...

Comment: What you mean with "vertically opposite"?

Comment: @Narasimham: maybe I'm wrong but I afraid your argument is not true. Take a look in my picture, if I keep everything stopped and move just the points $S$ and $R$ we keep with two "vertically opposite" angles but $P,O,S$ will not be collinear anymore.

Comment: Apologies. I corrected the error posted in hurry.